# construct only be used within computation expressions

Tags: f#

I'v an async function that returns a string asynchronously and I'm calling that function within test method and is throwing computation expressions, what would be the possible fix?

Code

```
let requestDataAsync (param: string) : Async<string> = 
    async {
        Console.WriteLine param
        return "my result"
    }
```

Test Code

```
[<TestMethod>]
member this.TestRequestDataAsync() =
    let! result = requestDataAsync("some parameter")

    Console.WriteLine(result)
    Assert.IsTrue(true)
```

Error for this line `let! result = requestDataAsync("some parameter")`

> > This construct can only be used within computation expressions

Question, How to wait and display the result of the async function?

Comment: Sounds like you want [`Async.RunSynchronously`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.runsynchronously%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D)

Comment: yesssss, I actually just found the answer too

Comment: to the down voter, what's the problem with the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer would be to use RunSynchronously. that way you can wait on the function call.

```
let result = "some parameter" |> requestMetadataAsync |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 5):

Calls to `let!` must appear at the top level of the computation expression. You can fix it by creating a nested async { } block:

```
[<TestMethod>]
member this.TestRequestDataAsync() =
async 
{      
    let! result = requestDataAsync("some parameter")
    Console.WriteLine(result)
    Assert.IsTrue(true)
 }
```

Comment: so the caller has to be within async block in order to call an async function ?

Comment: the execution control waits on the caller's async block or it just goes ahead with the rest of the statements?

Comment: The bang(!) operators only work in blocks of computation expressions. They only work for code immediately under the curly braces. So in short, it just goes with the statements, but needs to be inside the braces with the async keyword.

Comment: is there another way to wait on the async function result and without async block? in other words without using bang operator, If I'm not wrong the bang operator tells to wait for the answer of the expression, right?

Comment: Not any way that comes into mind, sorry. If my answer help you out, could you accept it ?